# python merging values according to "key" in list

Tags: python

Here I have a list of list:

```
[['a', 3], ['b', 2], ['b', 1.1], ['c', 5],['c', 1.2]]
```

How can i get a list of:

```
[['a', 3], ['b', 3.1],['c', 6.2],]
```

I could only think of some very clumpsy way.
looping the list with set() but is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary to store the values for each key. Then, make a list of lists from the dictionary elements.

```
data = [['a', 3], ['b', 2], ['b', 1.1], ['c', 5],['c', 1.2]]

mapper = {}
for pair in data:
    key, val = pair
    mapper[key] = mapper.get(key, 0) + val

data_merged = list(map(list, mapper.items()))
print(data_merged)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 3], ['b', 3.1], ['c', 6.2]]
```

**Explanation:**

- Declares an empty dictionary (`mapper`).
- Iterates each pair of elements.
- If the key is already in the dictionary then increase it by given value. Otherwise, set it is as the initial value.
- Creates a list of lists from the dictionary items.

Comment: +1, this works even when unsorted; but i believe `list(map(list, mapper.items()))` is equivalent to `list(mapper.items())`.

Comment: Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)`(int)`, it would work with `mapper[key] += val`

Comment: @MustafaAydın, thanks. FYI, `list(mapper.items())` returns a list of tuples of the elements. The OP wants a list of lists that is the reason to use `list(map(list, mapper.items()))`.

Comment: @arsho big thanks! i think i solved it with your method!

Answer (score 2):

If that list is sorted by its first elements as seen, then [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does the job:

```py
from itertools import groupby

[[key, sum(lst[1] for lst in group)] for key, group in groupby(a, key=lambda e: e[0])]
```

We group by the first entry of the sub lists. Then for each group, we sum the second elements and put them in a list along with the corresponding key which is the first element i.e. the letter we grouped on. The list comprehension gives the total answer thereby.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want but it's not very pretty:

```
my_list = [['a', 3], ['b', 2], ['b', 1.1], ['c', 5],['c', 1.2]]
[[key, sum(l[1] for l in my_list if l[0]==key)] for key in set([l[0] for l in my_list])]
```

Comment: a one liner without importing anything, +1! But i think some explanation about `set` and the inner list comprehension would help fasten the process of understanding it.

Comment: Thanks @MustafaAydın! Looks like our solutions are actually very similar. Your explanation kinda explains my answer too :D.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a default value of 0:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [['a', 3], ['b', 2], ['b', 1.1], ['c', 5],['c', 1.2]]

sums = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in data:
    sums[key] += value
    
out = [[key, value] for key, value in sums.items()]

print(out)
# [['a', 3], ['b', 3.1], ['c', 6.2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can solve it using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 3], ['b', 2], ['b', 1.1], ['c', 5],['c', 1.2]],columns = ['Letter','Value'])
df.groupby(['Letter']).sum().reset_index().values.tolist()
```